# Python Configs for quickfix

Tags: python-3.x, quickfix

This is the initiator config:

```
[SESSION]
ConnectionType=initiator
BeginString=FIX.4.1
SenderCompID=PS
TargetCompID=ND
SocketNodelay=Y
SocketConnectHost=48.40.87.16
SocketAcceptPort=9840
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=22:00:00
FileStorePath=C:/Temp/quickfix/store/initiator
FileLogPath=C:/Temp/quickfix/logs/initiator
ReconnectInterval=30
HeartBtInt=20
SocketReuseAddress=Y
UseDataDictionary=N
# DataDictionary=datadictionary/FIX41.xml
```

And this is the acceptor config

```
[SESSION]
ConnectionType=acceptor
BeginString=FIX.4.1
TargetCompID=ND
SenderCompID=PS
SocketNodelay=Y
SocketAcceptPort=9840
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=22:00:00
FileStorePath=C:/Temp/quickfix/store/acceptor
FileLogPath=C:/Temp/quickfix/logs/acceptor
SocketReuseAddress=Y
UseDataDictionary=N
```

I am sending a very simple message:

```
def create_message(self):

    print ("Composing Message")
    message = fix.Message();
    header = message.getHeader();

    header.setField(fix.BeginString("FIX.4.1"))
    header.setField(fix.SenderCompID("PS"))
    header.setField(fix.TargetCompID("ND"))
    header.setField(fix.MsgType("D"))
    message.setField(fix.OrigClOrdID("123"))
    message.setField(fix.ClOrdID("321"))
    message.setField(fix.Symbol("LNUX"))
    message.setField(fix.Side('B'))
    message.setField(fix.Text("Really Cancel My Order!"))
    return message

def test_fix(self):
    print ("Testing Fix")
    message = self.create_message()
    fix.Session.sendToTarget(message, self.sessionID)
    print ("Testing FIX ends")
```

My output on the initiator FIX.4.1-PS-ND.body does have the message it sent. However I am seeing nothing on acceptor. (1) What am I doing wrong/ (2) How does the initiator know where exactly (in this case anyway - TargetCompID=ND) where "ND" is?

Comment: I don't understand question (2), please explain.

Comment: "ND" is the TargetCompID. I was wondering how would a initiator recognize an acceptor. How do you maintain the uniqueness of the client IDs. There could be millions of TargetCompID=ND. We are specifying the initiator's IP address but not on the acceptor's side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want your initiator and acceptor to connect against each other. That will not work with your config because both have the **same** `TargetCompID` and `SenderCompID`.
For this to work, `TargetCompID` and `SenderCompID` need to be swapped on each end of the connection.

So the acceptor needs to have:

```
SenderCompID=ND
TargetCompID=PS
```

As long as both ends are not connected, calls to `Session.sendToTarget` will cause the message to be only written to the message store but not sent out. It will get sent out as soon as the session connects.

BTW, your initiator needs no `SocketAcceptPort` but a `SocketConnectPort`.
That should hopefully connect both ends. If not please paste error message.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am trying that now. Where do you get the error logs?

Comment: Thanks, I got something better this time: <20200115-14:16:24.000000000, FIX.4.1:PS->ND, event>
  (Connecting to 48.40.87.16 on port 9840 (Source :0)).. So it tried to connect to target port but nothing suggests the message was delivered. Where is the message delivered? I was thinking it would be FileStorePath on target machine?

Comment: BTW 48.40.87.16 is my IP address.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I was doing a very silly mistake. 
SocketConnectHost=48.40.87.16

This IP address should be acceptor's IP address. That actually answers my (2) question too.

Comment: In case you haven't found it already, here is a list of config options with description: http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html